# Mapbox GLJS - filter if value is in array

Tags: mapbox

How to add filter expression to show only features which has specific string  present in the feature property array? I was trying to use 'in':

```
['in', 'propertyArray', 'myString']
```

but does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had two issues. First was that value I want to check has to came first. The Second is that I needed to wrap array with expresion 'get'

```
['in', 'myString',['get','propertyArray']]
```